# MEAN Stack: How do you start Angular from Node, when Angular is inside Node folder

Tags: node.js, angular, mean

I have a MEAN stack app where I have my Node installation in a folder called 'myApp'. And, my Angular installation is in the 'myApp' folder and called 'Angular-src'. This is the base structure. So, it runs perfectly on my machine, locally. For Node, I use 'nodemon' on a command window, and 'ng serve' for the Angular on another command window.

But, I started having problems when I hosted this on Heroku. I followed the instructions, Build the Angular app for Prod, connected the MongoDB, deployed it, and when looking in the browser it indicates my Node server is running OK. But no sign of any Angular bit running. I looked a lot on the web but no clear answer.

I think this is something to do with my 'package.json' file, in "scripts" section. I have two 'package.json' files; one in 'myApp' folder for Node, and another one in the 'Angular-src'. These are the details:

(1) 'package.json' in Node folder -

```
{
  "name": "-----",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "-----",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "~5.6.0",
    "cors": "~2.8.5",
    "body-parser": "~1.19.0"
  },
  "author": "Harsha W. & Sujeewa B.",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

(2) 'package.json' in angular-src folder (long file truncated) -

```
{
  "name": "angular-src",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": { ...
```

(3) My app.js in the Node folder -

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dbConfig = require('./config/database');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

// Connecting with mongo db
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(dbConfig.database, {
   useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(() => {
      console.log('Database sucessfully connected')
   },
   error => {
      console.log('Database could not connected: ' + error)
   }
)
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

// Setting up port with express js
const coursesRoute = require('./controllers/courses.route');
/** other routes I have removed to unclutter the code **/

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: false
}));

app.use(cors())

app.use('/api/course', coursesRoute);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello HTTPS!")
})

// port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

http.createServer(app).listen( port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

**
What I need to know is how to serve Angular from my Node when my folder structure is like above.

Comment: Why do you need to deliver the source of your application? You can just deliver the built output of Angular

Comment: Thank you also Cristian Trania. Your help appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are deploying your source code to heroku instead of build version. Right now your `angular` server runs on `4200` as its in development but once you deploy it on `Heroku`. You will have just one port to work with (assigned by heroku).

Command to build angular app is `ng build` but dont just go and run this command (Read about it). This will take all your components and build couple of files in a folder which will be like `HTML files`, which in turn you can deploy.

Read about [Deploying Angular App](https://angular.io/guide/deployment). there are various tutorials on youtube where you can find how to deploy MEAN stack app on cloud.

Comment: I did `ng build --prod`, and I can see only a few files have beed created in the out folder. Is it right?

Comment: Yup. It should consist of `index.html`, `main.js` and others

Comment: Thank you Shivam, Your answer helped a lot. It also led me to a youtube video on **"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDYhwfi7VU0"** which described the whole scenario. Thanks again.